# Folio-Epicenter example (Julia + uibuilder)

Tags: julia

I'm trying to get the basic [Forio Epicenter example](https://forio.com/app/nathanielkale/watersheds/) from the documentation to work, using [Julia](https://forio.com/epicenter/docs/public/model_code/julia/)  and the [UI Builder](https://forio.com/epicenter/docs/public/ui_builder/).  It looks like this:

```
#in MyModel.jl

module MyModel

# use the Epicenter Julia package
using Epicenter

# expose methods you want to call 
# (e.g. using the Run API or Model Operation API,
#  or the Model Operation property of a component in UI Builder)
export doubleIt

# expose variables you want to view or update 
# (e.g. using the Run API or Model Variable API,
#  or the Model Variable property of a component in UI Builder)
export parameters, result

# make exposed variables global
global parameters, result

# define variables that the end user will change as part of a complex type
type ParametersType
    input1
    input2

    function ParametersType()
        item = new()
        item
    end
end

function doubleIt()
    global parameters
    global result

    result = parameters.input1 * 2
    record(:result)
end


# other files in your model
include("Utils.jl")
include("OtherModelCalculations.jl")

end
```

I can't get any variables to connect.  When I make a "Text Input" component and change the "Model Variable" property to match the Julia variable (exposed via "export" and "global"), loading the page gives me

```
400 Bad Request
```

Full JSON response:

```
{"status":400,
    "errors":{"status":400,
        "internal":{
            "procedure":"push!(LOAD_PATH, string(ENV[\"HOME\"],
            \"\/model\/\")); import Epicenter; using Juliet; using EpicenterSystem; EpicenterSystem.setup_idle_timeout
            (1800); require(\"MyModel.jl\"); using MyModel","sessionId":"c5b8189b-4f4d-4377-87a9-ca8d154863c0","trace":""}
    },
    "message":"Bad Request."
}
```

I've tried every combination of the "Model Variable" I can think of, including "input1", "parameters", and "parameters.input1"; always comes back with a 400 error.

Comment: Can you give a little more context and/or code so that one can see what you are doing and help?

Answer (score 0):

Forio Support here.

Two problems

a) since "input1" is a field in of variable parameters (type ParameterTypes), it must be referred to in the interface as "parameters.input1"

b) More importantly, the model attempts to include Utils.jl and OtherModelCalculations.jl, neither of which exist.  Thus the model never loads.